# Experience with CSLA in a WPF/WCF application

Tags: wpf, wcf, csla

Has anyone used CSLA in an application that has a WPF front end and a WCF wire for entities?

If so, which "entity framework" did you use? (nHibernate, Linq, etc...)
What were the hang-ups? What did it help you with?

I am concerned with implementing this for an application, not knowing how data-binding, validation with UI/entities, or deffered loading will react.

We are also worried about the message sizes coming over WCF, especially with the depth of our entities.

Are there any stress tests out there? I am trying to figure out what size application/entities this is really designed for.

If you can help answer any of these questions it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about CSLA, but I have built application with WPF + LINQ + WCF, This combination works well for one way databinding to WPF, but we need to have an intermediate  object class(ViewModel for WPF) to get the TwoWay working. This classes might be an exact copy of WCF classes(in most of the cases) but it would have INotiftPropertyChanged implemented.